# Arduino documentation on PCIFR and PINC

Tags: arduino-uno

I was reading this thread:

[Read RC receiver channels using Interrupt instead of PulseIn](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18183/read-rc-receiver-channels-using-interrupt-instead-of-pulsein/21233#21233)

and I have been trying to understand the code provided within.

While I was able to udnerstand most of it, I am still unable to find proper documentation on Arduino PCIFR and PINC?

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Arduino.SE. The documentation that you seek on `PCIFR` and `PINC` would not be documented under Arduino, this is as these are directly related to the ATMega328 (AVR Atmel micrcontroller) which is on the Arduino, they are [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR#Internal_registers) which are inside the microcontroller and `PCIFR` and [`PINC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR#GPIO_ports) are mnemonics.

For the ATMega328 you will find the documentation to these registers in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_complete.pdf) (a good read with coffee), or in tutorials written by others explaining this information in an easy to grasp way.

The `PCIFR` register is the Pin Change interrupt flag register(description on pg 73 of linked datasheet), this holds the flag bit to tell the microcontroller that there was an interrupt and runs the `ISR()` routine that one has set out. Read this [post](http://gammon.com.au/interrupts#reply6) by Nick Gammon on Pin Change Interrupts, and then read all of the post to get a better idea of interrupts in general.

The register `PINC` is for the inputs to the microcontroller, when one uses `staus = digitalRead(A0);` they are in effect using a wrapped up version of bitwise math and bit manipulation when simplified to `status = PINC & (1 << PC0);` thus `PINx` (x is for the register name ABCD) represents the state of the pin, either *HIGH(1, 5V, true)* or *LOW(0, 0V, False)*. Borrowing from the below linked tutorial:
[image: maxembedded]

Another nice description of the input ports [in this tutorial](http://maxembedded.com/2011/06/port-operations-in-avr/).

From the image you see that moving a bit to a position and then bitwise `&` that with `PINx` you will have a value returned if there is a 1 in **that** position.

```
 PINC      0b00001001    
(1 << PC0) 0b00000001    
         & __________    
status  =  0b00000001
```

The above shows how you only get the state of the first input and how the 4<sup>th</sup> input is ignored as it was not needed. Also worth noting PIN is the register description and is not the same as a physical pin that sticks out the IC's body.